# Web to case form fields pre-populated from another page

Tags: servicecloud, post, service, web2case

We have a Web to case form implemented in the force.com sites. This form has is being triggered from another VF page, with some parameters. One of the parameters holds the **Id** to another object from where I am fetching the values and feeding Web2Case form fields with it using VF remote objects. Now,

- if user doesn't change any of the **preloaded** fields and post the form **it works fine**
- but if the user changes any of the **preloaded** values in the form and post it, the case doesn't show the updated values instead it shows preloaded value(s).

> **Screenshot with original values**

[image]

> **Screenshot with updated values**

[image]

I am not sure which part of the code is gonna be relevant here, but will post it on the need-to-know basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been number of developers working on the web to case form and certain changes were unknown to me. During the debugging and analysis of the issue I found that there was a trigger that was overriding the values on the case object from another object, hence changing the fields back to their initial state.

After adding a condition in the trigger I was able to get around the problem, but just posting this answer so others could also check the back-end for triggers, process builder, and / or workflows that could be the likely cause of such irritating situation.